# Mvc 4 c# - Update WebGrid on main view after submit form on Modal popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a @Html.Beginform on partial view, that is open on jquery modal popup.
After submit a form, I want that the Webgrid on main view update without refresh page.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ajax.BeginForm and set UpdateTargetId to a Div that contains your Grid. In your edit action result, redirect to action to list grid.
You can use OnSuccess option if you want execute some script before update the grid. 
In this case, use Jquery `(("#idDivOfGrid").load(@Url.Action("ActionToListGrid", "Controller")))`.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
                        actionName: "YourEditAction",
                        controllerName: "YourController"   ,
                        ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId="idDivOfGrid"}                              
                        ))
{
    //Your form code...
}

//In the main view
<div id="idDivOfGrid">
 //your webgrid.    
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks.